# Flag declined but still mod deleted?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, moderators

I flagged this answer as not an answer (kinda starts as an answer but morphs into a separate question) but the flag was mod declined

[How write into CSV file properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702895/how-write-into-csv-file-properly/36045883#36045883)

At some point a moderator (Jon Clements) deleted the answer. Trying to understand what went on here

Comment: Well since the answer is a bit older, it would be interesting if the flag was declined at the same day? If not I could imagine that Jon just forgot to mark your flag as helpful, and later another mod saw that the answer is deleted and your flag was still there, so they may just declined it because a NAA on a deleted answer wouldn't help much.

Comment: You had actually flagged that as "very low quality", which got declined. Oddly, there were "not an answer" flags on that same answer that were marked as helpful at the same time. I've pinged Jon about this, so maybe he can explain.

Comment: Happens to me all the time ;)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Looks like I (incorrectly and with apologies) declined your VLQ flag and then deleted the post 3 seconds later anyway.

Since March 16th was a while back I'm going to take a guess that I fell into the trap of thinking it was a valid answer (that looked relatively salvageable - hence didn't need a mod to nuke it), so declined your flag separately, then was going to decline the NAA flags with the more specific "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" and at that point realised it wasn't really an answer anyway and deleted it.

Comment: The bylaws clearly state that you're not allowed to make mistakes.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Nobody is perfect, even this _little puppy_